# Configuring Alembic in Django Rest Framework with SQLAlchemy

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a DRF project where I am using SQLAlchemy along with Django's built-in ORM. For configuring Alembic into my project I did this.

Installed Alembic with `pip install alembic`

Then I've run this command on my root project directory.
`alembic init alembic`

This command generated a folder called *alembic* and a file named *alembic.ini* in my root project directory. Inside that folder there are some files like (*env.py, README, script.py.mako*) and a folder named *versions*.

Now, inside the *alembic.ini* file, I've added this line,

```
sqlalchemy.url = sqlite3:///db.sqlite3
```

This is how I configured.

This is my *models.py*:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, String, Integer, Float, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker, relationship
from django.contrib.auth import models


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db.sqlite3')
Base = declarative_base()


class PlaceInfoModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'place_info'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer,nullable=False)  
    name = Column(String(60))
    address = Column(String(300))
    rating = Column(Float)
    type = Column(String(20))
    image = Column(String)
    
    
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

In my *alembic/env.py* I added these lines:

```
from review.models import Base, PlaceInfoModel
target_metadata = Base.metadata
```

But, whenever I run this `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Created SQLAlchemy Model"` I am getting this error.

```
File "D:\SQLAlchemy Practice\env\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: The problem is the `from django.contrib.auth import models`, but you don't seem to use it. Why do you use SQLAlchemy with Django? It has its own ORM and migration system.

Comment: I know the fact that Django has its own ORM. But I have a requirement where I have to do this in order to maintain my project. It would be great if you could help me to solve the problem.